# How to make getopt_long() print nothing when there is error command-line arguments?

Tags: c, linux, glibc, getopt, getopt-long

I have a program use `getopt_get()` to parse command line arguments.
My code is like this :

```
int opt;
int optionIndex;
static struct option longOptions[] = {
    {"help", no_argument, NULL, 'h'},
    {"test", no_argument, NULL, 't'},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
}; 
while ((opt = getopt_long(argc, argv, "ht", longOptions, &optionIndex)) != -1) {
    switch (opt) {
        case 'h':
            help();
            return 0;
            break;
        case 't':
            init();
            test();
            return 0;
            break;
        case '?':
            help();
            return 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("default.\n");
    }
```

When I pass correct command line arguments to program, it works wells. 
But when wrong arguments are passed to program, it will print annoying and superfluous words like this.

For example, i pass wrong argument 'q' to program

```
$ ./program -q
./program: invalid option -- 'q'
Usage: -h -t
```

When there are wrong arguments, I just want it run my function `help()` without printing any word.

```
./program: invalid option -- 'q'
```

How can I stop `getopt_long` to print this annoying word and just print nothing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the [fine manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long)...

> If `getopt()` does not recognize an option character, it prints an error
>   message to *stderr*, stores the character in *optopt*, and returns '?'.
>   The calling program may prevent the error message by setting *opterr* to
>   0.

So, try this before calling `getopt_long`:

```
opterr = 0;
```

Comment: `opterr` is POSIX:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html, so even though `getopt_long()` isn't POSIX, it's likely to work.

Comment: Thanks, It work! And `opterr = 0;`  should  written before optget_long() as a flag.

Comment: A better online manpage link: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html . The bad editing in the old version clouds the fact that you can also suppress error messages by putting a colon at the front of the option string.